# android - Why my popup menu is black?

Tags: android, popup

I'm using built-in android popup menu but the result is this:
[image]

```
PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(context, holder.menu);
popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.item_menu, popupMenu.getMenu());
```

and the item_menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:title="item1"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:title="item2"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/three"
        android:title="item3"/>
</menu>
```

and the styles for the theme

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 5):

Likely to be the `Context` type:

Parent of my AppTheme is `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` and parent of my activity is `AppTheme`

```
// Background = black and textColor = black
PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(getBaseContext() , view); // don't use getBaseContext()

// Background = black and textColor = white
PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(getApplicationContext() , view); // don't use getApplicationContext()
```

so you must just use Activity Context:

```
// Background = light and textColor = dark
PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(YourActivity.this , view); // this is ok
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following in values-v14/styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
</style>
```

And change the PopupMenu style:

```
<style name="PopupMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I't didn't change anything, still black.

Comment: why is it black anyway? is there something wrong with my menu or theme? shouldn't the default be white? and why the text is black too?

Answer (score 1):

Check your app theme in manifest file It affects the views...

Comment: the app the is android:theme="@style/AppTheme"

Comment: navigate through appTheme in all res/styles folders and make use of light theme you will get it white

Comment: I have only one apptheme declaration, what do you mean?

Comment: OK but appTheme is customized as I pointed in my code, is there any thing else I can do?

Comment: No, just make sure that it uses light theme in parent theme

Comment: it's set to parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"

Comment: I've tried that too, I'm pretty sure there is something wrong with my application, it's not normal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82990/discussion-between-nilaydani-and-user3425760).

Answer (score 0):

People should understand how android works:

```
    <style name="AppTheme.Toolbar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">

    //This line changes the color of text in Toolbar
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/black_color</item>

    //This line changes the color of icons in toolbar (back, overfmenu_convmenu icons)
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>

</style>
```

This is a toolbar theme. Now see the parent `parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar"`

This is a dark android theme so here android internally plot a white popup and white icons. If you used light the theme like `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` Pop up will occur black. You can control + click and go inside these themes and check background of popupMenu already defined. So if you want white background use theme

```
Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar
```

Now must focus on these two lines.

```
//This line changes the color of text in Toolbar
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/black_color</item>

//This line changes the color of icons in toolbar (back, overfmenu_convmenu icons)
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
```

**android:textColorPrimary** 
is what you need to make black as your
text will not be visible if you set it to white on white background.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `popupMenuBackground` attribute to define the background color of your `PopupMenu` in your main theme.

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
     ...

     <item name="popupMenuBackground">@color/screen_white_background</item>
 </style>
```